# Finding position of encoder given range of data

Tags: excel, algorithm, sensors

I have an encoder data that ranges from 0 to +10000.  I need to know the arc position of the wheel.  I've calculated 1 revolution of the wheel to be 5570 counts.

In the end, I want to know the exact arc position and have it reset to zero whenever it's done a full revolution.

e.g.

```html
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <th>Raw Count</th>
    <th>Arc Position Count</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5000</td>
    <td>5000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5569</td>
    <td>5569</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5570</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10000</td>
    <td>4430</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>4431</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried using MOD(), but the problem arises when it goes from 10000 back to 0.  I get some wrong numbers.

I'm using Excel for this, but I was just wondering of a general algorithm.

Is there a general method to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: `=mod()` seems like the way to go. Why are you getting value 4431 when you are doing (I assume) a `=mod(0, 5569)`?

Comment: @JNevill, true, I think you're right in that I should be using 5569 rather than 5570.  That's where I will have to play around with it in order to confirm how to properly find the arc position.  It's a bit confusing because it's like saying that "360 degrees is also 0 degrees".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could handle your "360 degrees is also 0 degrees" problems by tracking complete revs and using an if statement. Here's some formulas that seem like they would give you plenty of info about each line:

[image]

---

**Text Version**

```
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Position | Adjusted =IF(A3<A2, 10000, 0) + FLOOR(B2, 10000) +A3 | =MOD(A2, 5569) | degrees  =(B2*360)/5569    | Condensed function =(MOD(A2, 5569)*360)/5569 | Complete Revs =FLOOR(A2/5569, 1) |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|        1 |                                                    1 |              1 |                0.064643563 |                                  0.064643563 |                                0 |
|     1200 |                                                 1200 |           1200 |                77.57227509 |                                  77.57227509 |                                0 |
|     3300 |                                                 3300 |           3300 |                213.3237565 |                                  213.3237565 |                                0 |
|     5569 |                                                 5569 |              0 |                          0 |                                            0 |                                1 |
|     5700 |                                                 5700 |            131 |                8.468306698 |                                  8.468306698 |                                1 |
|     1137 |                                                11137 |           5568 |                359.9353564 |                                  359.9353564 |                                1 |
|     1138 |                                                11138 |              0 |                          0 |                                            0 |                                2 |
+----------+------------------------------------------------------+----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

---

** UDF to solve this **

Stick this in a new module on your worksheet (in VBE)

```
Function arc(currentPos As Integer, prevSeq As Range) As Double
    'Set backwards threshold
    Dim backwardsthreshold As Integer
    backwardsthreshold = 100


    Dim tenThousandths As Integer
    Dim prevPos As Integer
    Dim capturedInitPos As Boolean

    'Loop through previous sequence to determine tenthousandths
    'as well as intitial position
    For Each rngPos In prevSeq.Cells

        'set initial position
        If Not capturedInitPos Then initialPos = rngPos.Value: capturedInitPos = True

        'Increment tenThousandths if we are skipping backwards and less
        'then our backwards threshold
        If prevPos > rngPos.Value2 And Abs(prevPos - rngPos.Value) > backwardsthreshold Then
            tenThousandths = tenThousandths + 1
        End If

        'set prevPos number for next iteration
        prevPos = rngPos.Value
    Next

    'Bump it the adjusted number
    currentPos = currentPos + (tenThousandths * 10000)

    'Subtract the initial position
    currentPos = currentPos - initialPos

    'determine arc
    arc = ((currentPos Mod 5569) * CLng(360)) / CLng(5569)

End Function
```

You can use it to calculate the arc one in one quick formula. For instance, to get the arc() for A4 in the table above, you would use:  `=arc(A4, $A$2:A3)`  That can be copied down and it will quickly generate the arcs. There is a `backwardthreshold` in there as well where it won't reset to the next 10000 if the difference between the current position and the previous position is less than 100 steps back. You can change that 100 to whatever makes sense.

Comment: This looks great, except remember that the encoder resets to zero "ticks" every 10000 "ticks".  Maybe I can work with it and see if I can combine this solution with MBo's solution as well (with the shift functionality).

Comment: I've updated the answer with a new column (B) that will adjust your resetting values appropriately. All of the other calculations are then based on that. You could stick that formula from `B` into your `MOD()` too if you want this to be a one column solution for row 3 that would look like `=(MOD(IF(A3<A2, 10000, 0) + FLOOR(B3, 10000) +A3, 5569)*360)/5569`

Comment: For the last data point (Position=1138), the "A8<A7" IF function doesn't play out (since A8<A7 is false, it returns zero) which makes the 2nd column = 1138.

Comment: It works as expected. We are adding up three things in that second function. 1) Did the sequence restart? If so, add 10000. 2)The number of 10000's from the previous number (for row 8 it will get 10000 from B7)  3) Whatever is in A8. Those three added up will give you the correct sequence adjusted for the 10000 reset. My example above is taken with that formula in place.

Comment: The first reading's formula should probably be different. Like it should jsut be a straight `mod(<number>/5569)`. the second row is where you start implementing this ugly formula since it always checked the previous row as part of the solution.

Comment: You're right.  I just made a small clerical error.

Another issue occurred.   Sometimes the encoder doesn't start at 1.  What if it starts at say, 8000?  I would want the arc (or degrees) to be 0 there and continue from there.  I'm still playing around with it, but any suggestions?

Comment: That's interesting. In that case, then subtract $A$2 (using the dollar signs to insure that we are always subtracting the initial position) from that second formula like: `=(IF(A3<A2, 10000, 0) + FLOOR(B2, 10000) +A3)-$A$2`

Comment: Oh, duh!  I forgot the extra parenthesis to keep the PEMDAS in order.  OK, I'll be putting all of this info in an edit, but one more occurrence that's possible, what if the encoder goes backwards?  Meaning, A3<A2, but it's not a jump.  It just goes from, say, 1000 to 900 (a -100 difference).  I think I would need another IF statement to catch that.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would know the difference. Whether it went from 1000 to 10900 or 1000 to 900. I guess you could test for the difference and if it's less than a certain amount, then implement logic to decrease. It's kind of ugly sounding.

Comment: Ya, that's what I was thinking.  I'll put what we found in my problem and mark this as solved.  Thanks!

Comment: Great! I'm updating the question now with a UDF that will spit out the output in one quick formula.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember last state and make correction for encoder value when it goes over 10000 border

```
current = encoder + shift
if last  - current > 5000 then  //too big jump down
     shift = shift + 10001
     current = encoder + shift
arc = current mod 5570  // 10001 mod 5570 = 4431
last = current
```